# Unable to return JSON data with Webflux authenticationFailureHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

Im building a React SPA and would like to interact with the back end using JSON. When an authentication fail I would like to be able to send a custom error message in the form of JSON. However given the code below:

```
    .authenticationFailureHandler(((exchange, e) -> {
      return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getExchange().getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        DataBuffer buf = exchange.getExchange().getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap("{\"test\":\"tests\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        response.writeWith(Mono.just(buf));
      });
    })
```

Im getting the follwing error:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
content-length: 0

<Response body is empty>

Response code: 200 (OK); Time: 1162ms; Content length: 0 bytes
```

However If I change response code it gets reflected in the response so I know the code is executed but no response body is returned.

What do I need to change to be able to send a response body back when authentication fails?

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work:

```
.authenticationFailureHandler(((exchange, e) -> {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getExchange().getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        DataBuffer buf = exchange.getExchange().getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap("{\"test\":\"tests\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(buf));
      });
    })
```

There might be a better way than writing JSON as a String, but I believe this should work.
Your attempt was not working because nothing was subscribing to the returned `Publisher` by `response.writeWith(Mono.just(buf))`. Since Publishers are lazy, nothing would get written to the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with a custom [WebExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api//org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.html) and [ErrorAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api//org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/ErrorAttributes.html)

```
.authenticationFailureHandler(webFilterExchange, exception) ->
     customErrorWebExceptionHandler.handle(webFilterExchange.getExchange(), exception);


@Component
public class CustomErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    public CustomErrorWebExceptionHandler(
            final CustomErrorAttributes customAttributes,
            final ResourceProperties resourceProperties,
            final ObjectProvider<List<ViewResolver>> viewResolversProvider,
            final ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer,
            final ApplicationContext applicationContext
    ) {
        super(customAttributes, resourceProperties, applicationContext);

        this.setViewResolvers(viewResolversProvider.getIfAvailable(Collections::emptyList));
        this.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        this.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {

        if (errorAttributes instanceof CustomErrorAttributes) {
            return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(),
                (request) -> handleProblemDetail(request, (CustomErrorAttributes) errorAttributes)
                        );
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(errorAttributes.getClass().getName());
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> handleProblemDetail(final ServerRequest request, final CustomErrorAttributes error) {

        final Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = error.getErrorAttributes(request, false);

        return ServerResponse.status(Integer.parseInt(errorAttributes
                .getOrDefault("status", "500").toString()))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON)
                .body(Mono.just(errorAttributes), Map.class)

                ;
    }
}


@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes implements ErrorAttributes {
    private static final String ERROR_ATTRIBUTE = CustomErrorAttributes.class.getName() + ".ERROR";

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(final ServerRequest request, final boolean includeStackTrace) {

        final Throwable error = this.getError(request);

        return somethingThatConvertsTheErrorToAMap(error);
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getError(final ServerRequest request) {
        return (Throwable)request.attribute(ERROR_ATTRIBUTE).orElseThrow(() -> {
            return new IllegalStateException("Missing exception attribute in ServerWebExchange");
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void storeErrorInformation(final Throwable error, final ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        exchange.getAttributes().putIfAbsent(ERROR_ATTRIBUTE, error);
    }
}
```